# De ladrar, ladrido; de maullar, maullido. ¿Y de piar?

Tags: vocabulario, animales

Le estaba explicando a unos niños cosas sobre unos pájaros (vencejos, concretamente), y me han preguntado que cómo se llama el sonido que hacen...
Les he respondido que «chirrido», porque estos pájaros hacen un ruido bastante chirriante, pero ¿cuál es la palabra genérica para el sonido de un pájaro al piar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Según el diccionario:

> **[piada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SrHwBko)**
>
> 1. f. Acción o modo de piar.

A mí no me suena nada bonito decir "la piada de las aves", preferiría decir "el piar de las aves", pero el diccionario no acepta "piar" como sustantivo.

Comment: No hace falta que un verbo sea registrado como sustantivo para usarlo como tal.  Se puede nominalizar los verbos bien simplemente usándolos como tal bien anteponiéndoles un determinante (normalmente *el*)

Comment: @guifa ¿entonces es gramaticalmente correcto decir "el ladrar del perro", por decir "ladrido"?

Comment: sí, no hay problema aunque para mí tiene un significado ligeramente diferente.  Me cuesta pensar en cómo explicarlo pero se compara bien con el inglés: *el ladrar* sería *the barking* (solo significa la acción) y *el ladrido* sería *the bark* (una acción singular, varias conjuntamente, o el modo/forma de sonar).

Comment: No obstante, tampoco soy nativo, así que puede que las connotaciones que conllevan cosas para mí no coinciden con las que tienen los nativos.

Comment: @guifa - ¿Cuál es tu idioma materno, pues?  (o cuáles son)

Comment: @aparente001 inglés

Comment: @guifa - Ah, fíjate que nunca me dí cuenta.

Comment: los verbos en infinitivo pueden ser utilizados como sustantivos, tambien puedes gregar "cion" , miento" y "ado/ada"  y "ido/ida" lo que veo es que piar según la rea se transformo en piada mediante una de estas reglas  (ado/ada)

Answer (score 6):

Buscando en el diccionario llegué a la palabra

> [piular](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TGTPGkJ) 
>  1. intr. Dicho del pollo: piar (‖ emitir cierto sonido). 
>  2. intr. Suspirar o clamar por algo.

La cual sí tiene un sustantivo asociado:

> [piulido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TGVaKh8) 
>  1. m. Acción de piular.

Pero aclaro que yo nunca he escuchado que esta palabra sea utilizada.

Comment: ¡Qué buen descubrimiento.!

Answer (score 4):

De *piar*, [***pío***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T6Li1tV%7CT6QbqG1%7CT6VGC0P):

> [image]
>
> - [*Using Spanish: A Guide to Contemporary Usage*](https://books.google.es/books?id=eEWZL1j9ig8C&q=p%C3%A1jaro), By R. E. Batchelor, C. J. Pountain (1992)

Además, hay los sinónimos:

- [piular](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TGTPGkJ) → [piulido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TGVaKh8) (del catalán)
- piar, [piolar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T6s0RWt), [pipiar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=T7Rkvd8) → pío

Answer (score 3):

El verbo se puede usar como sustantivo:

**piar**

Compárese con ["De Cuba Traigo un Cantar" de Carlos Puebla](http://bangos.info/letra-de-cuba-traigo-un-cantar-carlos-puebla_125107)